# AngularJs - $injector:modulerr error because dependency loading after controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm using ng-table in an AngularJs project. In my html i'm calling ng-table script file before my controller but (Because of size, i guess) controller is loading before ng-table and giving $injector:modulerr error.

How can i make sure ng-table will load first or bootstrap the app again after all dependencies are loaded?

My html:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="serveriphere/Assests/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="serveriphere/Assests/Scripts/ng-table.js"></script>
<script src="serveriphere/Controllers/TopStreaksController.js"></script>
```

And in my controller:

```
var widgetApp = angular.module('widgetApp', ['ngRoute','ngTable']).config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
});

widgetApp.controller('topStreaksCtrl', function ($scope, $http,$filter, ngTableParams) {
```

stack trace ([link](https://s22.postimg.org/62qcig9xd/Screen_Shot_2015_04_02_at_20_16_00.png))

[image: stack trace]

controller line 133:

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['widgetApp']);
```

Comment: I don't think your diagnostic is the right one. Post the code, and post the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @JBNizet which part of the code do you want? It's happening on first load.

Comment: By the way, i'm not getting the exception all the time. But i checked from network tab, whenever app is loading correctly ng-table is loading before controller and every time exception happening ng-table is loading after controller.

Comment: How do you "load" scripts? Show your html file. Show how you declare your modules.

Comment: @JBNizet added details, please check if this is what you wanted to see.

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception? Is it the only place you call angular.module()? Do you have other scripts loaded by the page?

Comment: @JBNizet added stack trace as image. Please follow link for big image. That's the only place i call module() and those are the all scripts i'm loading. Also added last line of controller as it's referenced in stack trace.

Comment: Did you add angular.bootstrap inside  `angular.element(document).ready` function?

Comment: Also, why don't you use ng-app?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap the application once the page has finished loading.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
          angular.bootstrap(document, ['widgetApp']);
});
```